# write csv in one cell

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I want to write the following script to write in one cell. Currently the script creates 2 columns, but I only want to write it in one cell. See below for the desired output format.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

URL = 'https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/20/byd-planning-model-3-like-800-volt-sedan-called-seal/'
(response := requests.get(URL)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')


paragraphs = soup.find('section', class_='content').find_all('p')
# the sources in the last paragraph
sources = paragraphs[-1].find_all('a')
# put the sources name and link in a dict
sources_links = []
for source in sources:
    sources_links.append(f"{source.text}({source['href']})")

# write in csv
with open('electrive_scrape_source.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Source'])
    csv_writer.writerow(sources_links)
```

Desired output in one csv cell - separated with a comma:

```
xchuxing.com (https://xchuxing.com/article/45850), cnevpost.com (https://cnevpost.com/2022/02/18/byd-seal-set-to-become-new-tesla-model-3-challenger/)
```

Comment: What's the point of writing to CSV if you cram everything on one line? Proper design would instruct you to write one record per row, and divide it into logical fields as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

First to get the comma separated string we can use the [`'some delimiter'.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function to combine everything in the list into a single string separated by that delimiter. For the delimiter you'd use either `','` or use `', '` if you would like to automatically add spaces after the commas.

Then secondly, because [`csv_writer.writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) expects a list (or some other iterable) we need to wrap our comma separated string in a list, thus creating a list that only has one item in it. Like so.

```
csv_writer.writerow( [ ', '.join(sources_links) ] )
```